# How to set the color of a qml TreeView indicator

Tags: qt, qml

How can I change the color of the indicator in a TreeView?
I tried using branch delegate

```
style: TreeViewStyle
{
    branchDelegate: {
        color: "red"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Considering the [source code](https://github.com/qt/qtquickcontrols/blob/5.12.2/src/controls/Styles/Base/TreeViewStyle.qml) as the base, the solution is as follows:

```
style: TreeViewStyle {
    branchDelegate: Item {
        width: indentation
        height: 16
        Text {
            visible: styleData.column === 0 && styleData.hasChildren
            text: styleData.isExpanded ? "\u25bc" : "\u25b6"
            color: "red" //!control.activeFocus || styleData.selected ? styleData.textColor : "#666"
            font.pointSize: 10
            renderType: Text.NativeRendering
            style: Text.PlainText
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            anchors.verticalCenterOffset: 2
        }
    }
}
```